# Probability that at least 1 machine breaks down

Tags: probability, statistics

In the manufactoring plant of a company two large production machines are used. Machine A breaks down with probability of 0.01, whereas a breakdown of machine B occurs with probability 0.005. Further, if machine A breaks down the probability of a breakdown of machine B is equal to 0.1. What is the probability that the production stops, i.e. at least one of the production machines breaks down?

Basically, my solution so far is:
C - event of interest where at least one production machine breaks down (=1-C¬)
C¬ - complement of C, aka production doesn't stop as no machines break down

P(A) = 0.01 ==> P(A¬) = 1-0.01=0.99
P(B) = 0.005 ==> P(B¬) = 1-0.005 = 0.995
P(C¬)=P(A¬)*P(B¬)=0.98505 chance that no machine will break down

==> 1 - 0.98505 = 0.01495 chance that at least 1 machine will break down and production will stop

However, I feel like I'm missing something because this solutions seems just too easy and I don't know what is P(BlA)=0.1 given for (from: "Further, if machine A breaks down the probability of a breakdown of machine B is equal to 0.1")

Any insight will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, read the MSE [$\texttt{MathJax}$ Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Thanks.

Comment: This approach looks fine to me.

Comment: We have P(B) << P(A). So the final probability will depend majorly on P(A).

So we can see that the final answer = 1 - (P(A) + P(B)) which is approximately equal to P(A) = 0.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the addition rule:
$$\begin{align}P(A\cup B)&=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=\\
&=0.01+0.005-P(A)\cdot P(B|A)=\\
&=0.01+0.005-0.01\cdot 0.1=\\
&=0.014.\end{align}$$
Also, note:
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)=P(B)\cdot P(A|B).$$